# Define type for array of array or number and use spread operator

Tags: typescript

I am trying to figure out how to define type for Array which has both Array and a number.

```
input: [[2,7,11,15], 9]

// I tried
input: Array<Array<number> | number>
```

However, when I use this with spread operator then it throws an error `A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.`

```
tests.forEach((test) => {
  console.log(twoSumHashMap(...test.input))
})

const twoSumHashMap = (nums, target) => {
  let map = new Map(), required;

  for(let i = 0; i<nums.length; i++) {
    required = target - nums[i];
    if(map.has(required)) {
      return [map.get(required), i]
    } else {
      map.set(nums[i], i);
    }
  }
}
```

```
const tests: Array<{input: Array<Array<number> | number>, expected: Array<number>}> = [
  {input: [[2,7,11,15], 9], expected: [0,1]},
  {input: [[3,2,4], 6], expected: [1,2] },
  {input: [[3,3], 6], expected: [0,1] }
]
```

#### Workaround

Perhaps I don't need to use spread operator here and can simply use this since input will always be 2 element.

```
tests.forEach((test) => {
  console.log(twoSumHashMap(test.input[0], test.input[1]))
})
```

Is there a better pattern to use typescript here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `twoSumHashMap` expects only two arguments. Arrays might have sizes other then 2, so you should explicitly type `input` as a tuple with two items ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmADgVygLhgbTMgtgIwFMAnTAXQBoYcCSyYBeGLTAJgoHYKBGbngVkowAnGQCwAKEmhIsKAHcQAZTwAJAIYQAFgFl1iRjAAUNCFSjriAc0JQAlIwB8MAN6TmAG1sxc%20w2EJ5GD1EIzsqYkIAR2Q4SIATAG5JdxgAMxBiIy9YOEMABkT4AB5TADovMCsoLSK4AGp6hzcJZmZImLjCeMMLa28AWmo8CEw4MmTWtrg0o19EMq1NIw7YhLtm1LaYSKhkYjAsebKbKBXote7w%20HEp5gBfGEIPCEJXLbbj17PTMaE4OyTbb3VIgiRg6TgCAgLwVEBWIwKZRqTS6fRGMqYhAoex2IA)):

```
input: [number[], number]
```

Your function should also have a return value if it can't find two numbers, and types for the inputs ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmADgVygLhgbTMgtgIwFMAnTAXQBoYcCSyYBeGLTAJgoHYKBGbngVkowAnGQCwAKEmhIsKAHcQAZTwAJAIYQAFgFl1iRjAAUNCBhpFSQqOuIBzQump5LASkYA%20GAG9JzGdAwuPqGYITyMHqIRq4A3JJ%20MABmIMRGADaO8IYADLHwADymAHSZYHZQWvlwANQ17r4SzP7ggcSEAI7IcO0AJoY29lkAtM64EJhwZPFNzYnMcElGwYjFWppG7V09hL2uDfPN7VDIxGBYK8UOUJud3X2uVFOHAL6Hh5cQjiZ4E1NPcUSbyks2Op3O2GQ6XSVGG3GmkmB0laIEypRAdiMCmUak0un0RmKRIQKCg%20yAA)):

```
const twoSumHashMap = (nums: number[], target: number) => {
  const map = new Map();

  for(let i = 0; i<nums.length; i++) {
    const required = target - nums[i];
    
    if(map.has(required)) {
      return [map.get(required), i]
    }
    
    map.set(nums[i], i);
  }

  return [null, -1];
}
```